# Is it possible to prevent LUDecomposition from pivoting?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, options

By construction, `LUDecomposition` performs LU-decomposition with pivoting; i.e., with row permutations (otherwise, the decomposition may not exist). Is it possible to tell *Mathematica* not to use pivoting in cases when the decomposition can be performed without it?

Comment: It seems LAPACK does not have a no-pivot routine, but [MKL does](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-mkl-getrfnpi).  I can't find an access point within Mathematica, but maybe there is some way to use it.

Comment: This seems to work `N@LUDecomposition[SetPrecision[m, Infinity]]`, but it will be slower than machine precision.

Comment: @MichaelE2 if `BLAS` has it Mathematica might expose that.

Comment: @b3m2a1, the [subset of level-3 BLAS in *Mathematica*](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LowLevelLinearAlgebra/guide/BLASGuide.html) does not have a routine for LU decomposition.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I might be remembering incorrectly, but I believe the exact integer/rational case also uses a pivot strategy, just a different one from the approximate numeric case.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to cheat `LUDecomposition[]`:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; mat = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {3, 3}]];

{lu, piv, cond} = LUDecomposition[Map[Interval[{#, #}] &, mat, {2}]] /.
                  Interval -> Mean;

Norm[(LowerTriangularize[lu, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length[lu]]).
     UpperTriangularize[lu] - mat, ∞]
   6.66134*10^-16
```

---

As another example, let's use this trick to get the Cholesky triangle corresponding to a symmetric positive definite matrix:

```
mat = N[HilbertMatrix[6]];
lu = First[LUDecomposition[Map[Interval[{#, #}] &, mat, {2}]] /. Interval -> Mean];
```

Form the Cholesky triangle:

```
ch1 = DiagonalMatrix[1/Sqrt[Diagonal[lu]]].UpperTriangularize[lu];
```

Compare with the result of `CholeskyDecomposition[]`:

```
Norm[ch1 - CholeskyDecomposition[mat], ∞]
   1.15992*10^-13
```